# sort items in listview.builder [ Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview.builder inside a Future builder I want to sort the  items to displayed depends on time

example:

my listview like that now

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and what I want is somthing like that:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCv7H.png

```
List<int> items = [1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> reversedItems = items.reversed.toList();
```